# Wikipedia api python returns weird results

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, pywikibot

```
import wikipedia

print(wikipedia.summary("Tomato", sentences=3))
```

Why does this code return a disambiguation error with "tom tom" and not just a summmary/disambiguation error to the entry "tomato"?
The search term is clearly not tom tom or am I missing something here? Why doesnt this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching for `"Tomato"` leads to the suggestion `"tom tom"`. Not sure why... In any case, you can disable `auto_suggest` in `wikipedia.summary`:

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia.summary("Tomato", sentences=3, auto_suggest=False)
```

The output is

```
'The tomato is the edible, often red, berry of the plant Solanum lycopersicum, commonly known as a tomato plant.  The species originated in western South America and Central America. The Nahuatl (the language used by the Aztecs) word tomatl gave rise to the Spanish word tomate, from which the English word tomato derived.'
```

You can see that searching for `"Tomato"` suggests `"tom tom"` using the `wikipedia.search` function:

```
results, suggestion = wikipedia.search("Tomato", suggestion=True)
```

The `suggestion` is `"tom tom"`, and `results` is a list of titles that are closely related to tomato.

Comment: yeah I was aware of that but my main confustion was, that the search "Tomato" leads to "tom tom" I just wanted to be sure if I missed something.

Thanks anyways!